# Защита формы без капчи

Tags: php, форма, защита, captcha

Посоветуйте, хотелось бы сделать защищенную форму на сайте без использования капчи. Что я сделал:

1. Ввел сессионную переменную с генерированным закодированным значением, которое помещается в поле формы. При получении формы поле hidden сравниваю с этим значением. При несоответствии, естественно, выводится соответствующее сообщение и форма не попадает под обработку.
2. Ввел еще одну сессионную переменную, которая следит, чтобы форму невозможно было отправить чаще 1 раза в час. То есть после отправки формы при обновлении страницы, ее html-разметка вообще не появляется на странице в течение часа.

Вопрос: какие подводные камни содержит мой скрипт и что  можно ожидать от веселых хакеров? В частности интересует возможность или невозможность отправки данной формы со стороннего ресурса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте так, чтобы поля содержали рандомные имена, причем все были типа "text", или подобных, которые заполняют боты. И одно-несколько полей сделайте visibility:hidden. Если бот их заполнит, то форма не проходит.

От ручного спама так-то и капча не спасет.

Comment: @lampa, сколько лет, сколько зим! Я слышал про скрытые поля и рандомные имена. Для таких имен придется инициировать дополнительные сессионные переменные? А как бот может обойти мое условие, что форма не принимается чаще 1 раза в час?

Comment: @Deus, легко, индентификатор сессии хранится в куках. Чистые куки, чистый заход на страницу)

Comment: @Deus прокси да разные аккаунты.

Comment: @Alex Krass, я только об этом подумал и тут же подтвердили. Хотя, только что я пробовал отправить форму с другого скрипта - не получилось))) форма не имеет правильный идентификатор в этом случае

Comment: @lampa, поподробней с защитой по адресу где можно ознакомиться?

Comment: @Deus так просто ip адрес запоминаете, с которого было сообщение оставлено и запрещаете ему на час пользоваться формой.